# Send multiple HTMX HX-Trigger events in header from Django and trigger multiple events in html

Tags: html, django, htmx

I have two elements that I want to re-render after updating data in the db.
The two html dom elements are:

```
<div hx-trigger="revealed, update_location_graph_{{location.id}} from:body" 
     hx-target="#plot_div_{{location.id}}" 
     hx-get="{% url 'location-progress' location.id %}">
   <div id="plot_div_{{location.id}}">
   </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div hx-trigger="revealed, update_group_graph_{{ location.id }}_{{ group.id }} from:body" 
     hx-target="#plot_div_{{location.id}}_{{group.id}}" 
     hx-get="{% url 'group-progress' location.id group.id %}">
   <div id="plot_div_{{location.id}}_{{group.id}}">
   </div>
</div>
```

The one is a graph for all the groups of a location and the other is a graph for only one group in one location.

In Django I want to send up two events to trigger the two updates in one response.  Django code as follows:

```
    trigger1 = f'update_group_graph_{ location.id }_{ group.id }'
    trigger2 = f'update_location_graph_{ location.id }'
    return HttpResponse(status=204, headers={'HX-Trigger': {trigger1:"a", trigger2:"b"}})
```

I got the dictionary idea from [this](https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/) link on htmx's site, but this seems to only work for js listeners.

Any ideas on how to send or receive these events correctly?

Comment: Perhaps the header content needs to be a valid json string rather than a dict. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71999325/htmx-and-django-return-hx-trigger-header-with-json-data-show-error-syntaxerror

Comment: you can try to use trigger_client_event  from django-htmx, which will handle the json encoding for you.

Comment: @SamSparx, your comment is on the money.  If you can make it a response I'll mark it as the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @ChristoLabuschagne I think the linked answer by solarissmoke did the heavy lifting here :-) Feel free to give it an upvote to improve it's score.